# WPF toolkit DateTimePicker giving incorrectly formated value

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datetimepicker, wpftoolkit

I am trying to get `DateTimePicker` value in `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format.`DateTimePicker` code is

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="startDateTimePicker" Value="{Binding SelectedDate}" 
FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" Width="280" Height="30" Watermark="Select DateTime"/>
```

I have mentioned the Format string as I want but it's giving me output as `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`. Not getting why this is happening. My system date time is `MM/dd/yyyy` will that affect the result. If yes, how can I nullify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Format` property to `Custom` for the `FormatString` to be applied.

Try this:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="startDateTimePicker" Value="{Binding SelectedDate}" 
                     Format="Custom"
                     FormatString="dd\/MM\/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" Width="280" Height="30" Watermark="Select DateTime"/>
```